# JS Animation only works with alert() after page refresh

Tags: javascript, css, submit

Got a submit type button that triggers a Javascript function, which has this code:

```
function spin() {


        alert("spinning");
        document.getElementById("rouletteImage").removeAttribute('style');

    var deg = 180;

    var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';

    document.getElementById("rouletteImage").setAttribute(
        'style', css
    );
}
```

also this line in css:

```
    img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 4s ease-out;
}
```

Now, this code works perfectly and the spinning animation is smooth, however, for some reason, when i remove the `alert()` from the function, the image still gets rotated by `deg`, but there isnt any anymation, it just plain spawns rotated already.

Could someone give me any insight?

Comment: can you create a codepen or [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07qsvzea/7/)

Comment: document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transform = "rotate(7deg)"; try this instead

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

```
<img src="" id="rouletteImage"  />
```

Javscript function

```
function spin() {

 document.getElementById("rouletteImage").className ('someClass');

}
```

Change css like

```
img.someClass {
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Let me know if not working